# flutter: Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. on Android

Tags: sqlite, flutter, sqflite

I stuck at this error for a month I cannot find any solution via google.
I build a chat app which need to work both online and offline, backend is NodeJS
Below code is send any message that still in pending to target devices

```
  async function _worker(socket) {
    console.log('worker running...')
    await connect.then(async (db) => {

        // When user A sent message to user B but user B is offline so server need to sync this message to user B
        Message.find({ isDeliver: 0 }).then(async (m) => {
            if (m.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
                    let sender = m[i].sender;
                    let receiver = m[i].receiver;
                    let online = await checkUserOnline(socket, receiver);
                    if (online) {
                        let to_user_socket_id = getSocketIDfromMapForthisUser(`${receiver}`)
                        sendToConnectedSocket(socket, to_user_socket_id, "send_message_to_device", m[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

         // When user A sent a message to user B and user B is offline but when user B is online and message delivered to user B and user A is offline server need to sync this message status to update for user A
         Message.find({ isDeliver: 1 }).then(async (m) => {
            if (m.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
                    let sender = m[i].sender;
                    let receiver = m[i].receiver;
                    let online = await checkUserOnline(socket, sender);
                    if (online) {
                        let to_user_socket_id = getSocketIDfromMapForthisUser(`${sender}`)
                        sendToConnectedSocket(socket, to_user_socket_id, "send_message_deliver", m[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // When user A sent a message to user B and user B is offline but when user B is online and read the message and user A is offline server need to sync this message status to update for user A
        Message.find({ isRead: 1 }).then(async (m) => {
            if (m.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
                    let sender = m[i].sender;
                    let receiver = m[i].receiver;
                    let online = await checkUserOnline(socket, sender);
                    if (online) {
                        let to_user_socket_id = getSocketIDfromMapForthisUser(`${sender}`)
                        sendToConnectedSocket(socket, to_user_socket_id, "send_message_read", m[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    });
 }
```

and below is a method to handle event from server:

> Socket

```
setOnServerSendDeliver(Function  onServerSendDeliver) {
    _socket.on('send_message_deliver', (data) {
        onServerSendDeliver(data);
    });
  }

  setOnServerSendRead(Function  onServerSendRead) {
    _socket.on('send_message_read', (data) {
      onServerSendRead(data);
    });
  }

  setOnServerSendToDevice(Function onServerSendToDevice) {
    _socket.on('send_message_to_device', (data) {
      onServerSendToDevice(data);
    });
  }
```

> Method

```
 onServerSendDeliver(data) async {
    MessageModel message = MessageModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(data));
    await G.dbService.updateDeliver(message);
    G.socketUtils.sendDeliveryDone(message, new UserModel(id: message.sender));
    refreshMessage();
  }

  onServerSendRead(data) async {
    MessageModel message = MessageModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(data));
    await G.dbService.updateRead(message.chatId);
    G.socketUtils.sendReadDone(message, new UserModel(id: message.sender));
    refreshMessage();
  }

  onServerSendToDevice(data) async {
    MessageModel message = MessageModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(data));
    ChatModel chat = new ChatModel();
    chat.id = message.chatId;
    chat.fromId = message.sender;
    chat.toId = message.receiver;
    chat.message = message.content;
    await G.dbService.chatOperation(chat);
    await G.dbService.insertMessage(message);
    await G.dbService.updateDeliver(message);
    G.socketUtils.sendDelivery(message, new UserModel(id: message.sender));
    refreshMessage();
  }
```

in server I set

`setInterval(_worker, 1500, socket);`

to load check message and send to end devices

and my database function

```
Future<String> updateRead(String chatId) async {
    Database db = await database;
    try {
      await db.transaction((txn) async {
        return await txn.rawUpdate(
            "UPDATE messages SET isRead = 1, isSend = 1, isDeliver = 1 WHERE chatId = ? AND status = 0",
            [chatId]);
      });

      await db.transaction((txn) async {
        return await txn.rawUpdate(
            "UPDATE chats SET isRead = 1, isSend = 1, isDeliver = 1 WHERE id = ? AND status = 0",
            [chatId]);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    return chatId;
  }

  Future<String> updateDeliver(MessageModel message) async {
    Database db = await database;
    String id;
    try {
      id = message.id;
      await db.transaction((txn) async {
        return await txn.rawUpdate(
            "UPDATE messages SET isDeliver = 1 WHERE id = ? AND status = 0",
            [message.id]);
      });

      await db.transaction((txn) async {
        return await txn.rawUpdate(
            "UPDATE chats SET isDeliver = 1 WHERE id = ? AND status = 0",
            [message.chatId]);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    return id;
  }
```

iOS is working fine but on android I always got this error and my app stuck:

> flutter: Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use the transaction object for database operations during a transaction

Any help would be appropriate

**Update**

I tried to modify the database function to:

```
Future<String> updateDeliver(MessageModel message) async {
    Database db = await database;
    String id;
    try {
      id = message.id;
      await db.transaction((txn) async {
        var batch = txn.batch();
        batch.rawUpdate(
            "UPDATE messages SET isDeliver = 1 WHERE id = ? AND status = 0",
            [message.id]);
        batch.rawUpdate(
            "UPDATE chats SET isDeliver = 1 WHERE id = ? AND status = 0",
            [message.chatId]);
        batch.commit();
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    return id;
  }
```

but I still faced the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to `await` any async method in a transaction:

```dart
await batch.commit();
```

You should use pedantic (or the proper lints) to get a warning when you forget such `await`.

And yes, don't create a transaction for a single operation and try to group actions in transaction (and batches if you can).

You could also [turn on logging](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/dev_tips.md#turn-on-sql-console-logging) to make sure you are not doing too many sqlite queries.

Comment: I used a transaction for a single operation this is just for testing due to I can't get rich of this issue

Comment: @CeebLajThoj any progress about the issue ?

Comment: I can't get rich of the issue so I changed to use firebase.